# How to send email using wp_mail() on button click - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sorry, i'm asking again. I know this question already answered here: [How to send wp_mail on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143329/how-to-send-wp-mail-on-button-click)

But, i'm already do it like the answer on the forum. But still not working properly. Here is my code:

```
function send_mail_form(){
        ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name ="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="your name"><br />
                <input type="text" name ="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="your email"><br />
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject" placeholder="your subject"><br />
                <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="your message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

                <?php submit_button('Send', 'primary', 'send'); ?>
            </form>
            
        <?php
       
        if($_POST["send"]){
            $to =  esc_attr($_POST["name"]);
            $subject =  esc_attr($_POST["subject"]);
            $message = esc_attr($_POST["message"]);
            $headers = esc_attr($_POST["email"]);
            wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            echo "<script> alert('email is sent!');</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<script> alert('something wrong!');</script>";
        }

    }

add_shortcode('send_mail_form', 'send_mail_form');
```

When I insert the shortcode in test page, localhost keep alert "something wrong". I also already insert this code into functions.php theme:

```
function phpmailer_init( $phpmailer ) {
        $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
        $phpmailer->Host = SMTP_HOST;
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
        $phpmailer->Port = SMTP_PORT;
        $phpmailer->Username = SMTP_USER;
        $phpmailer->Password = SMTP_PASS;
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
        $phpmailer->From = SMTP_FROM;
        $phpmailer->FromName = SMTP_NAME;
   
    }
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'phpmailer_init');
```

and also already insert SMTP Email Settings into my custom plugin, like this:

```
define( 'SMTP_USER', 'hendratrisno@gmail.com' );
define( 'SMTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com' );
define( 'SMTP_FROM', 'hendratrisno@gmail.com' );
define( 'SMTP_NAME', 'Hendra' );
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '587' );
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'TLS' );
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );
```

but still not working... I've been searching for answers for hours. I hope I can get help to find what is wrong in the code. Thank you, developers!

Comment: Install this plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-toolkit/) and activate it. Visit the page again where you used shortcode and update your question. The plugin will show errors if any. You can deactivate it once going live.

Comment: I already install it, but show no error in the page.

Comment: Does it still say 'something wrong' when you visit that page ?

Comment: yes still say something wrong. And after I click send, the page reload and then the form disappear. Page not found.

Comment: This should solve your issue : https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Comment: Enable the [debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), that will give you more details about the error than just "something went wrong".